# with tomcat manager, how to take application version from manifest.mf instead of war filename

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war, manifest.mf

In Tomcat manager v7, the only way i found to show version of app deployed, is to add version tag to war filename with "appname##versiontag.war" synthax.

I need to upload a generic file wihtout version, but i need anyway to have version in manager application list.

Is there a way to tell manager to get the application version in configuration file instead of war filename (e.g. in manifest.mf or context.xml) ?

any idea ?